# While exporting as csv file, file is getting downloaded but with name and with no extension MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-csv

While exporting as csv file, file is getting downloaded with file name and with no extension MVC the following code is used,

This happens only after deployment to servers, in local its working as expected.

```
 public static KeyValuePair<string, string> ConvertDTtoExcel(DataTable dt, string filename)
            {
                string fileName = filename + ".csv";
                string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + fileName;
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                try
                {
                    response.Clear();
                    response.ClearHeaders();
                    response.ClearContent();
                    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                    response.ContentType = "application/csv";
                    response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    string tab = string.Empty;
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
                        tab = ",";
                    }
                    response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                    int newRow;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        tab = string.Empty;
                        for (newRow = 0; newRow < dt.Columns.Count; newRow++)
                        {
                            response.Write(tab + dr[newRow].ToString());
                            tab = ",";
                        }
                        response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    response.Flush();
                    response.End();
                    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, response.ContentType);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Error(string.Format("Method Name: ConvertDTtoExcel, Error Occurred {0}", ex.ToString()));
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've not got the "Hide file extensions for known types" checked on your prod servers when you browse the folders via explorer?

Comment: You can create your own ActionResult by inheriting from FileResult and just override WriteFile() method.  It will save you a bunch of grief when interacting with the Response.

Comment: @wheels73 how to check the extensions supported in servers??

Comment: @Fran - You open windows explorer, choose "Folder & Search options", choose the "View" tab and un-check the checkbox option for "Hide extensions for known file types" if selected.  Simple test is to see if you can see any file extensions on the disk. E.g. .txt

Comment: @Wheels73 I understand that's probably the issue.  I'm just trying to tell the OP there's an easier way with less code so that he can be more confident that the issue isn't his code.

Comment: @Fran - Sorry chap.. i didn't mean to direct that at you...it was meant for OP! :)